# Ubuntu 16.04 update problem about third party repositories

Tags: apt, 16.04, updates

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and I get update problems after installing skype. When I try to install updates by using Software Updater, it stops and gives an

> The package system is broken

error. And says:

> Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them,
>   since they are a common source of problems. Furthermore run the
>   following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f

I disable third party repositories and even remove mendeley from the list but the problem did not solved. I tried `apt-get install -f` command, it gives also problem and says:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Execute the command as a root

`sudo apt-get install -f`

You need elevated privileges for the package manager.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Don't `try` just do, answer with confidence.

Comment: Thx Mark :), message just look to me so familiar

Comment: @TalipZengin If this solved your issue, press the checkmark on the left to thank the user who helped you.

Comment: @IvanMarjanovic You were right :) You just need to say it with confidence.