# ubuntu not updating neither installing anything (Package system is broken)

Tags: package-management, system

Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
Transaction failed: The package system is broken
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
gdm3: Depends: libaudit1 (>= 1:2.2.1) but 1:2.8.2-1ubuntu1 is installed
      Depends: libgdm1 (= 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.4) but 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.4 is installed
      Depends: libwrap0 (>= 7.6-4~) but 7.6.q-27 is installed
      Depends: gir1.2-gdm-1.0 (= 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.4) but 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.3 is installed
      Depends: bash (>= 4.3) but 4.4.18-2ubuntu1.2 is installed
      Depends: x-terminal-emulator but it is a virtual package
      Depends: x11-common (>= 1:7.6+11) but 1:7.7+19ubuntu7.1 is installed
gir1.2-mutter-2: Depends: libmutter-2-0 (= 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.1) but 3.28.3-2~ubuntu18.04.2 is installed
gnome-shell: Depends: libgjs0-libmozjs-52-0 but it is a virtual package
             Depends: gir1.2-mutter-2 (>= 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.1) but 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.1 is installed
             Depends: gnome-shell-common (= 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.1) but 3.28.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.4 is installed
             Depends: mutter (>= 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.1) but 3.28.3-2~ubuntu18.04.2 is installed
libgl1: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
        Depends: libglvnd0 (= 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.3) but 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2 is installed
        Depends: libglx0 (= 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.3) but 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2 is installed
policykit-1: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
             Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3) but 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4 is installed
             Depends: libpolkit-agent-1-0 (= 0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.5) but 0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.4 is installed
             Depends: libpolkit-backend-1-0 (= 0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.5) but 0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.4 is installed
             Depends: libpolkit-gobject-1-0 (= 0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.5) but 0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.4 is installed
```

Comment: Did you already run `sudo apt clean` and `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt -f install`  and `sudo apt upgrade`? Also, did you modify your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file or did you add any ppas? Please edit your question and include this information. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 16.04 update problem about third party repositories](https://askubuntu.com/a/816635/167115)